# MIPS program to replicate itself?

Tags: memory, assembly, mips

How can I create a mips program such that in the main function it prints out version1 and then copies the entire code into memory and finaly executes the copied version. The copied version of the code must print version2. You cannot add anything in the data section other then version1 and version2.

How to I copy the entire code into memory and execute it? I've never done anything like this before so I don't know where to start.

```
.data
   version1:    .asciiz   "This is version1"
   version2:    .asciiz   "this is version2"

main:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, version1
    syscall
    #(how do I copy code and execute it?????)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to self modify the code is dependent on the environment of execution.
With MARS this option can be enabled.
The code assume Little Endianness for data memory (no assumption for code memory).

What your professor probably want is this:

1. That you recognize that `la` is a pseudo instruction made of `ori` and `lui` so that you correctly count the instruction to be copied as four.
2. That you reserve space in the program flow for four instructions using `nop`.
3. That you recognize the instruction format to edit the operands.

The copy process is simple. You can get aided by the assembler by a cleaver use of the labels: just put a label right after the code to copy (and right before if there are none) and then copy all the data between these two.
Since we know the length of the code to copy and it is small, we can copy by hand.

In order to modify the copied code we need to see how it look likes as machine code

```
addiu $v0, 0, 4      #24020004
lui $at, HHHH        #3c01HHHH
ori $a0, $at, LLLL   #3424LLLL
syscall              #0000000c
```

As you can see you have replace the lower HW of the 2nd and 3rd instruction.
The value to use is the address of *version2*.
The upper and lower HW of this address can be obtained with basic bits manipulations.

You also have to add the code to terminate the program nicely.

Here an **intentional simplified** working example made for MARS (activate the Self Modify Code in the settings).

```
.data
   version1:    .asciiz   "This is version1"
   version2:    .asciiz   "this is version2"

.text

main:
    li $v0, 4               #1 instruction  addiu $v0, $0, 4
    la $a0, version1            #2 instructions lui $a0,  H  ori $a0, L
    syscall             #1 instruction

    #Load src and dest address
    la $t0, main
    la $t1, new_code

    #Copy the four words of code
    lw $t2, ($t0)
    sw $t2, ($t1)
    lw $t2, 4($t0)
    sw $t2, 4($t1)
    lw $t2, 8($t0)
    sw $t2, 8($t1)
    lw $t2, 0xc($t0)
    sw $t2, 0xc($t1)

    #Load the address of version2
    la $t0, version2

    add $t2, $0, $0 
    lui $t2, 0xffff     #t2 = 0ffff0000h

    andi $t3, $t0, 0xffff       #t3 = Lower HW of address
    srl $t0, $t0, 0x10      #t0 = Upper  HW of address

    #Edit ori $a0, L
    lw $t4, 8($t1)      #Load the instruction in register
    and $t4, $t4, $t2       #Clear lower hw
    or $t4, $t4, $t3        #Set lower hw 
    sw $t4, 8($t1)      #Save the instruction

    #Edit lui $a0, H
    lw $t4, 4($t1)      #Load the instruction in register
    and $t4, $t4, $t2       #Clear lower hw
    or $t4, $t4, $t0        #Set lower hw 
    sw $t4, 4($t1)      #Save the instruction


new_code:
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop

    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

If you are interested in a more generic version that dynamically allocate the memory (with syscall 9), align the returned pointer, copy the code, modify it and add the call to syscall 10, here it is

```
.data
   version1:    .asciiz   "This is version1"
   version2:    .asciiz   "this is version2"

.text

main:

__copy_start__:                 #Sign the start of code to copy
    li $v0, 4               #1 instruction addiu $v0, $0, 4
    la $a0, version1            #2 instruction2 lui $a0,  H  ori $a0, L
    syscall             #1 instruction
__copy_end__:

    li $v0, 9               #Allocate buffer
    li $a0, 27              #16 bytes (4 instructions) + 8 bytes (2 instructions) + 3 byte for aligning
    syscall                 

    #Align the pointer by consuming the first bytes (this is usually not needed, just for completeness)
    addi $v0, $v0, 3            
    andi $v0, $v0, 0xfffffffc

    #Prepare for the copy
    la $t0, __copy_start__      #t0 = Source start
    la $t1, __copy_end__        #t1 = Source end (exclusive)
    add $t2, $0, $v0            #t2 = Destination start
    ori $t4, $0, 1          #t4 = 1: Extra code to be copied 0: Extra code copied

do_copy:
    #Move from Source to Dest
    lw $t3, ($t0)           
    sw $t3, ($t2)

    #Increment the pointers
    addi $t0, $t0, 4
    addi $t2, $t2, 4

    #If not reached the Source end, copy again
    bne $t0, $t1, do_copy

    #Copy done
    #If the extra code has been copied, do the jump to the new code
    beqz $t4, do_jump

    #Extra code need to be copied
    la $t0, __copy_extra__      #New source start
    la $t1, __copy_extra_end__      #New source end
    add $t4, $0, $0         #Signal extra code is being copied

    #Copy again
b do_copy               

do_jump:    
    #Get the address of version2
    la $t0, version2

    #Save the low half word into the low halfword of the 3rd instruction (ori $a0, L)
    sh $t0, 8($v0)
    #Get the upper hw in the lower hw of $t0
    srl $t0, $t0, 16
    #Save the high half word into the low hw of the 2nd instruction (lui $a0, H)
    sh $t0, 4($v0)

    #Jump indirect
    jr $v0

    #Extra code to append to the end of the new code
__copy_extra__:
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
__copy_extra_end__:
```